# How to change section/content on clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have the following problem: i have 5 buttons and after loading the webpage there must be nothing but those 5 buttons. After clicking a button there should appear text and on clicking other button should be other text, for example i clicked button2 an below appeared text "button2", then i clicked button4 and "button2" changed to "button4"

im using Laravel, and i stuck on this stage. All i need is answer to this question in Js or PHP, doesnt matter. if it works i will adapt answer to laravel. thks very very much

Comment: `All i need is answer to this question` - what question? If you knew nothing of the scenario and read the above would you understand exactly what was meant? And SO is not a code request type site....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work as intended (comment if you have problems with it) :

```js
// We run the code once the window has loaded so that we can access `document.body`
window.onload = () => {
  // we get all buttons with the `btn` class
  const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
  // we create the span which will display our text
  const span = document.createElement('span')

  // buttons is and `HTMLCollection` so we need to cast it to `Array` to accès the `forEach` method
  Array.from(buttons).forEach(btn => {
    // when the button is clicked, we set the displayed text of the span with the text set in the `data-txt` html attribute set on all the buttons
    btn.onclick = () => span.textContent = btn.dataset.txt
  })

  // we add the `span` to the DOM (here in the body but we could in any other `HTMLElement`
  document.body.append(span)
}
```

```html
<!-- we create all the buttons with the `btn` class so it will be selected in our `js` and we also set the `data-txt`, of course you can change the text which will result in changing the displayed text -->
<button class="btn" data-txt="Button 1 clicked !">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-txt="Button 2 clicked !">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn" data-txt="Button 3 clicked !">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn" data-txt="Button 4 clicked !">Button 4</button>
<button class="btn" data-txt="Button 5 clicked !">Button 5</button>
```

Comment: It would help if you explain your answer a bit more, explain the details in the initial answer.